# I can see my model in solid view but I can't see then in rendered view and when I render the image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I just finished Blender Guru's donut tutorial in 2.82 and I wanted to recreate a scene from MIDWAY. I downloaded a model of the Akagi, and one of a Dauntless dive bomber. The Akagi rendered great. (pic below)
But when I tried to render the dauntless, it just became transparent. Maybe its the texture? I joined the dauntless' parts before I rendered. (pic below) BTW I am using cycles. Here are the files. 
Akagi: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/akagi-5fb1484e62a9417097dbd46f74095989
Dauntless: https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/douglas-sbd-3-685c95ec16a94c1b8d500615e5d3ec0f
And here is my .blend: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tsxQ7Ur9suhdmytct4-fdjDyD3vC_Ode
EDIT: it shows up black in lookdev mode too.[image]
Here is the material for the dauntless:[image]

[image: this is the Dauntless in solid view mode]

this is the transparent Dauntless in the rendered view
[image: this is the transparent Dauntless in rendered view]
this is the rendered Akagi
[image: this is the rendered akagi]
Here is the material for the dauntless:

[image]

EDIT: it shows up black in lookdev mode too.

---

UPDATE: the reason the dauntless color is visible in solid view is because viewport display is set to navy blue. I changed it to neon green and this is the result, however I still don't know how to see the colors in rendered view mode.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using blender 2.8 or higher there can be a "bug" when using older files where it doesn't show if things will be shown in renders. you can enable it manually like this.

[image]

A greyed-out camera means it won't show up in the render.

Comment: I tried that and it still is transparent :(
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj8aO.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xj8aO.jpg)

Comment: still doesn't work :(

Comment: UPDATE: the reason the dauntless color is visible in solid view is because viewport display is set to navy blue. However I still don't know how to see the colors in rendered view mode.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUrrS.jpg